Getting query list from Room to populate DropDownMenu
Building a database with multiple tables. The tables are used to track component usage but I'm having a hard time getting a Query List to populate in a DropDownMenu. I want to limit the users to the List so my Foreign Key will work easier. When I have Log.d output what should be the List it always outputs an empty list []. Hopefully the code below is enough to show my issue.
Database:
@Database(
    entities =[Bullet::class, Ammo::class],
    exportSchema = false,
    version = 1
)
abstract class BBDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: BBDao
}

@Entity (tableName = "Ammo", )
data class Ammo (
    val ammoName: String,
    val ammoBulletName: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val ammoID: Int=0
)

@Entity (tableName = "Bullet")
data class Bullet (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val bulletName: String
)

Dao:
@Query("SELECT bulletName FROM Bullet")
fun getBulletNames(): Flow<List<BulletNames>>

data classes:
data class BulletNames(
    val bulletName: String,
)

data class AmmoState(
    val bulletName: List<BulletNames> = emptyList(),
)

Event:
sealed interface AmmoEvent {
    data object ShowDialog : AmmoEvent
}

ViewModel:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class AmmoViewModel(
    private val dao: BBDao,
) : ViewModel() {
    

    val bulletName = dao.getBulletNames()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, emptyList())

    fun onEvent(event: AmmoEvent) {
        when (event) {
            AmmoEvent.ShowDialog -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        isAddingAmmo = true,
                        ammoBulletName = "",
                    )
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
}

MainScreen:
@Composable
fun AmmoScreen(
    state: AmmoState,
    onEvent: (AmmoEvent) -> Unit
){
    Scaffold (
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                onEvent(AmmoEvent.ShowDialog)
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add Ammo")
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {_ ->
        if(state.isAddingAmmo){
            AddAmmoDialog( state = state, onEvent= onEvent)
        }
}

DialogBox:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AddAmmoDialog(
    state: AmmoState,
    onEvent: (AmmoEvent) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bulletOptions = state.bulletName
    var selectedBullet = ""


    AlertDialog(
        modifier = modifier,
        onDismissRequest = { onEvent(AmmoEvent.HideDialog) },
        confirmButton = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    onEvent(AmmoEvent.SaveAmmo)
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Save")
                }
            }
        },
        title = { Text(text = "Add Ammo") },
        text = {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = state.ammoName,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onEvent(AmmoEvent.SetAmmoName(it))
                    },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Ammo Name") },
                    label = { Text(text = "Ammo Name") },
                )

                ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
                    modifier = modifier,
                ) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = selectedBullet,
                        onValueChange = {},
                        label = { Text(text = "Select Bullet") },
                        trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .menuAnchor()
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    ExposedDropdownMenu(
                        expanded = expanded,
                        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
                    ) {
                        bulletOptions.forEach { item ->
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                                text = { Text(text = item.toString()) },
                                onClick = {
                                    expanded = false
                                    selectedBullet = item.toString()
                                    onEvent(AmmoEvent.SetAmmoBulletName(item.toString()))
                                },
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}


Please [edit] your question and reduce the code to a [mre]. Make sure to remove everything that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem while providing everything that is needed, like the Room Entity. Also please make sure that there is actually data in the database by checking the Database Inspector.

I've verified that there are items in the table I'm trying to Query. My problem boils down to getting the Flow<List> to populate into the ExposedDropdownMenu in the AddAmmoDialog. Thanks

I asked to reduce the code. Please remove everything that isn't essential to demonstrate your problem. The events are not needed, the sorting is not needed, and I don't see how anything related to Ammo is needed. But the Room Entitiy Bullet is still missing. This is way too much irrelevant code. Also, please explain why a simple property in the view model doesn't suffice, like val bulletNames = dao.getBulletNames().stateIn(...).

Sorry about adding more code. I originally tried using .stateIn() but couldn't get the values to populate in the Screen or in the AlertDialog. I have 2 tables. The Bullet entity has it's own ViewModel and Screen(not included above) where I can enter the Bullet details into the Bullet table. I need to Query just the bullet names so I can link/assign a bullet to an Ammo in the ammo table

What is AmmoViewModel's onEvent? It doesn't compile and it isn't even called anywhere. What is isAddingAmmo? Can it be removed for the sake of this example? What is AmmoEvent.HideDialog, AmmoEvent.SaveAmmo, AmmoEvent.SetAmmoName and AmmoEvent.SetAmmoBulletName? They are nowhere defined, so I guess they can be removed? AmmoState has no ammoName property declared, yet you access it... why is that still needed? And most importantly, where is the bulletName property accessed? The example needs to be minimal and reproducible. Please [edit] accordingly.

From leviathan's suggestion above to use
val bulletNames = dao.getBulletNames().stateIn(...)

I added the following:
private val _bulletOptions = dao.getBulletNames().stateIn(viewModelScope, 
SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

which returned a StateFlow<List<>>. In order to update the List<> in my data class I needed the return to be in the form of List<>. To do this I used the following:
val state = combine( _bulletOptions) { bulletOptions -> 
state.copy(bulletOptions = bulletOptions)}.stateIn(viewModelScope, 
SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), 
AmmoState())

If the mods don't feel this thread is relevant or helpful please feel free to remove/delete
